# How can I use str.partition with a text file to split a question and answer for a quiz

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a quiz which uses an external text file. The textfile looks like:

1. Are apples green?TRUE
2. Are pears green?TRUE
   etc etc

I have used `x.partition("?")[0])` to split between the question mark so question is to the left and answer to the right.
When I run the program however, the answer doesn't seem to match the `csAnswer` and I'm not sure why.
I have tried `csAnswer.rstrip` but it still outputs 'incorrect'.

How can I amend this?

```py
def csQuestions():
    for x in questionFile:
        print(x.partition("?")[0])
        answer = input("Input answer, TRUE OR FALSE: ")
        csAnswer = (x.partition("?")[2])
        csAnswer.rstrip("\n")
        print("cs is ",csAnswer,"answer input is ",answer)
        if answer == csAnswer:
            print("correct answer")
        elif answer !=csAnswer:
            print("incorrect")
```

Comment: Have you tried printing ```csAnswer```?

Comment: Yes, to see what was wrong i wrote
print("cs is ",csAnswer,"answer input is ",answer)

Comment: And what was the output for that?

Comment: Probably a space on the front of csAnswer - use `.strip()`

Comment: Why are you using `[2]` to get the answer (and why do you partition the string twice? Do it once and collect the parts)?

Answer (score -1):

Try like this (Use `.strip()` and assign to the variable):

```
def csQuestions():
    for x in questionFile:
        que,ans = x.split("?")
        print(que)
        answer = input("Input answer, TRUE OR FALSE: ")
        csAnswer = ans
        csAnswer = csAnswer.strip()
        print("cs is ",csAnswer,"answer input is ",answer)
        if answer == csAnswer:
            print("correct answer")
        elif answer != csAnswer:
            print("incorrect")
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 i think it strips the spaces and unwanted things, so it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, I wouldn't do it with partition, I would modify the text file so that it is Are apples green?"TRUE so that we can use the split method like this:

```
for questionandanswer in questionFile:
     question = questionandanswer.split('"')[0]
     answer = questionandanswer.split('"')[1]
```

When running your code the code got confused with spaces, etc, now that wouldnt happen anymore. I reccomend using this(its ur code but modified for .split):

```
questionFile = open(r'C:\Users\incan\OneDrive\Documentos\Code\try.txt', 'r')
def csQuestions():
    for x in questionFile:
        print(x.split('"')[0])
        answer = input("Input answer, TRUE OR FALSE: ")
        csAnswer = x.split('"')[1]
        csAnswer.rstrip("\n")
        print("cs is ",csAnswer,"answer input is ",answer)
        if answer == csAnswer:
            print("correct answer")
        elif answer !=csAnswer:
            print("incorrect")

 csQuestions()
```

Comment: Thanks! Much less confusing than what i was doing